# Circuit for choosing one power supply from several of them

Tags: power, mosfet, switching, review

I have a load and four different voltage sources. I want to change the voltage on the load by using four different enable signal as seen in the schematic below. Note that, all of the "Enable" signals are active low, and only one of the enables can be logic-low at the same time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDG6Da.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I designed the reusable "Switching Circuit" block as seen below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYcDPt.png)</sup>

The working principle is like this:

When the **Enable** signal is **0V**,
**M1** conducts. At first, **M2** might not conduct, but its body diode will conduct and make the **Vout** voltage positive. Then, the gate of **M2** will be more negative with respect to its source. Therefore, **M2** will conduct. The power applied to **Vin** will be transferred to **Vout**.

When the **Enable** signal is **5V**,
Since the voltage at **Vin** will be equal to or less than 5V, **M1** will have a non-negative **Vgs** voltage, and thus, it will not conduct. But, remember that the outputs of all the "Switching Circuit"s are connected together. So, if another "Switching Circuit" conducts and the voltage it is conducting has a value higher than this "Switching Circuit"s **Vin** voltage, the body diode of **M1** will let it pass backwards and will cause a disaster to happen. For preventing this situation, we are using the **M2** mosfet. When **Enable** is 5V, the **Vgs** of **M2** will be positive, and **M2** will not conduct. **Vout** port will be seen in Hi-Z state.

I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66339/switching-between-two-voltage-supplies) similar question. It is about choosing between only two supplies. Similar to Bitrex's answer there, I can remove (i.e.; not solder) the mosfet **M2** from the circuit which is switching the highest voltage. This is the only improvement I can see. Is there anything wrong with this design? Is it going to work as intended? Please make suggestions to improve this design.

Comment: +1 for well elaborated question! Your circuit (M1+M2) shows an ideal diode. You need to keep M2 in case the output would be still high when the sourcing power switches to a lower voltage. The body diode of M2 will then protect the body diode of M1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works in principal, but has some drawbacks.

With a 1.8 V supply, your PMOS load switch will only see a Vgs on of -1.8V, that is fairly low. You likely won't achieve the FET's rated RDSon. Secondly, running a FET below its ZTC point can result in hot-spotting on die due to the negative tempCo of the threshold voltage.

Personally, I would move to a NMOS design where you use a charge pump to a achieve a gate drive signal above the input supply rail. You can roll your own design, or buy a load switch driver IC.

As you likely know, you will want to design some enable logic to ensure you break before make any of your load switches to avoid back-feeding onto the lower supply rail.

Comment: Also you should consider what happens when you have leakage current through the substrate diode D2.

Answer (score 1):

sstobbe's answer helped me. I decided to redo my design according to his idea of using a charge pump to generate **10V** from the **5V** supply. I used it to replace P-channel mosfets with N-channel ones.

This is the final solution I decided to use.

[image: Alternative Circuit]

I generated **+10V** by using a charge pump. **M_ls** is used for level shifting the input control signal **Disable**. The **Disable** signal takes values of either **0V** or **5V**. The level translated **Vg** signal takes values of **10V** and **0V** respectively.

The control signal **Disable** comes from a SP4T/BBM type slide switch. Each branch of the switch is connected to one of these switches. Pole of the switch is connected to **Gnd** net. Therefore, the **Disable** input signal of a switch circuit is either **0V** or **floating**. The resistor **Rvd1** makes the circuit disabled by default if the **Disable** input is floating. The resistor **Rvd2** makes sure that the **Disable** signal does not exceed **5V** value, because the maximum allowed value of **Vgs** for **M_ls** is **8V**. If another mosfet is used, this resistor can be removed.

Value of **Vs** is guarantied to be between **1.8V** and **5V** all the time. If **Vg** is **0V** (**Disable**=**5V**), both mosfets are turned off, since **Vgs** will have a negative value. If **Vg** is **10V** (**Disable**=**0V**), both **M1** and **M2** are turned on, since **Vgs** will have a value higher than **5V**.